# SSH2.php is there a way to increase time for a response from server?

Tags: php, libssh2

I seem to get these errors sometimes;

`Unable to open channel in /home/Net/SSH2.php on line 3833`

And was wondering if there was a way to mitigate these issues by increasing time to wait for a response?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By setting the timeout, like this:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('hostname');
$ssh->setTimeout(10);
```

Comment: how long of a timeout is `10` ? seconds? milliseconds?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://api.phpseclib.org/1.0/Net_SSH2.html#method_setTimeout) does not say buy I'm 99% sure it's in seconds.